# params with array values get separated by commas when transitioning to a state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have just started using angular Ui router and I was trying navigate to another state with some parameters.

Let's say following is my parameters object:

```
{
  a:[1,2,3,4],
  b:["1","2","3","4"]
}
```

and the state I am transitioning to is like:

```
.state('main', {
  url: 'hello/:q?a&b',
    ...
});
```

I expect the url to be like

```
hello/query?a=1&a=2&a=3&a=4&b=1&b=2&b=3&b=4
```

but the url is like

```
hello/query?a=1,2,3,4&b=1,2,3,4
```

So the $stateParams.a has a value `1,2,3,4` while I expect it as an array

angular-ui-router ~0.2.10

angular 1.2.*

Note: I know I can use `split()` to separate the values but I was looking for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this link

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/373

It appears that this feature is set for milestone 0.4.0